# Hide empty header of primefaces subtable

Tags: css, primefaces

I have a set of subtables that is fed from the managed bean, and they may or may not have a header text.

```
<p:dataTable var="xxxxx" value="#{}" styleClass="xxxxx" emptyMessage="#{}">
  <f:facet name="header">#{}</f:facet>
<p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
        <p:column headerText="xxxxx" />
    </p:row>
</p:columnGroup>
<p:subTable var="xxxxx" value="#{}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText rendered="#{}"
                value="#{}" />
    </f:facet>
    <p:column style="text-align:center;">
        <h:outputText value="#{}" />
    </p:column>
    </p:column>
</p:subTable>
</p:dataTable>
```

> > Only structure shown. Tag contents wiped on purpose.

when the subtable header is empty text, it still renders a thin empty header line. Is there any way I can supress the exibition of that header in case empty?

Using PF 3.5 on Tomcat 7 (mojarra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supress the exibition of the empty header of the subtable by using this CSS property:

```
td.ui-datatable-subtable-header:empty {
  display: none
}
```